# isAuthenticated() not working with my custom authentication provider .?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new with spring security ,
I have made a custom authentication provider to check if the user haw access to the secured page or not via database.
every thing was ok, but when I added `<intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" />` to security configuration an error occurs !

this is my **userService** :

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws   AuthenticationException {
     Logger logger = null;
     logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
     PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    name= auth.getName();
    pwd=auth.getCredentials().toString();
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken ret=null;
    String select_auth= "select username,password from users where username=? and password=?";

    try {
        connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select_auth);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,pwd);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            logger.info("user <"+name+"> is connected");


           ret= new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, null);}
        else
        {
        ret= null;
        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this is my **seurity-config**

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/403" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

could someone help me ,or explain me what's the cause of the problem ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073834/spring-security-custom-authenticationprovider-is-called-twice-and-fails/29078757#29078757 maybe can help?

Comment: Thanks @holmis83 , it helped me a lot ! :)